# Add a hyperlink in AppCenter Release Notes

Tags: bitbucket, fastlane, appcenter, release-notes

is it possible to add a hyperlink in AppCenter's Release Notes.
BTW I am using Fastlane to push the build and to add the Release Notes as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitbucket provide URL for creating a new branch.
You need to configure the URL Parameters with the appropriate Info and add it in the AppCenter ReleaseNotes.

URL:

xxxBASEURLxxx/plugins/servlet/create-branch?branchType=release&repoId=[REPO_ID]&branchFrom=refs/tags/[APP_NAME]-v[VERION_NUMBER]-[BUILD_NUMBER]&branchName=[BRANCH_NAME]"